# The path for form_tag is not right

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a small Rails 4.2 app to modify records in a few db tables which are in 2 rails engines. A rails app is created for this purpose. There is only one controller `user_menus` with no model.

```
class UserMenusController < ApplicationController

  def home

  end

  def doper
    #update db records

  end
```

The `home.html.erb` is a form to enter some params for update.

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => 'user_menus', :action => 'doper', :method => 'get') do %>
     <div class="form-inputs">
       <%= label_tag(:db_name, "Release") %>
       <%= select_tag(:db_name, options_for_select([['',''],['Engine Config', 'engine_config'], ['User Access', 'user_access'], ['Search Stats', 'search_stats']])) %>

      <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
        </div>
  <% end  %>
end
```

In `routes.rb`, there are definitions:

```
  get '/handler', :to => "user_menus#doper"

  root :to => "user_menus#home"
```

The problem is that I am having hard time to make right the the path for `form_tag`. The error is:

```
No route matches {:action=>"doper", :controller=>"user_menus", :method=>"get"}
```

The following `<%= form_tag('/handler') do %>` is not working as well:

```
No route matches [POST] "/handler"
```

In `rake routes`, there is a definition for `/handler`. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a route for your action, might as well use it

```
form_tag '/handler', method: :get do
```

And yes, using GET requests to produce side-effects is bad. Why don't you use POST for this?

Comment: This one asking for the view template for `doper`. Changed to `method: :post` and the error is the same (missing template of `doper`)

Comment: Well, your routes must agree with what you use in the form. Make sure they do. And also, `doper` action must render something. Fix that too.

Comment: What's the right way to declare a route in routes.rb which is for update of collection of records (with no data model)? I tried `post /handler, to: 'user_menus#doper` or `patch. At the end of `doper`, it will redirect. The all db update should be carried out inside `doper`.

Comment: Given that you don't have a proper resource, we don't talk about RESTful methods here. So can be just `POST /handler`. Certainly not `GET`

Comment: Yes, it is without data model. I just generated a blank doper.html.erb and it seems fixing the problem. Also use `patch /handler ...` in `routes.rb` and `method: :patch` for `form_tag`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here, your form tag passing method get. You can check your form method by inspect element.

By default form tag takes form method. You can override it, here you need to change syntax.

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "user_menus", :action => "doper"}, {:method => "get"}) %>
or

<%= form_tag({:controller => "user_menus", :action => "doper"}, :method => "get") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `<%= form_tag('/handler') do %>` by default the verb is `post`.
Try adding

```
post '/handler' => "user_menus#doper"
```

to your routes.

Answer (score 0):

*Add the name "as handler_path" to your route*

get '/handler', to: "user_menus#doper, **as: :handler_path**

*Your form_tag:*

form_tag handler_path, {method: "get"} do